# What is a good way to transfer a tensor (indicating location) to mask?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a loc tensor with batch_size 2 and length 5. I want to generate mask_trg tensor based on loc tensor.
The loc tensor indicates the current location of the current batch.
For example, the loc[0, 2] = 2 indicating the mask_trg[0, 2] = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0] because current location is 2 and all the path marked as 1.

I tried multiple ways but not sure what is efficient way (vector-based) to generate that mask_trg tensor?

```
loc = tf.constant(
    [
        [1, 1, 2, 2, 4],
        [1, 2, 4, 4, 4]
    ])

mask_trg = tf.constant(
    [
        [
            [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ],
        [
            [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ],
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = tf.one_hot(ptr, 5)
print(y)
y2 = tf.cumsum(y, axis=-1, reverse=True)
print(y2)

tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]

 [[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]], shape=(2, 5, 5), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]], shape=(2, 5, 5), dtype=float32)
```

I think y2 is what you want.